# Probability of getting 50 heads is equal to the probability of getting 51 heads

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$100$ coins are tossed. Probability of getting $50$ heads is equal to the probability of getting $51$ heads.that probabiity is $.....?$

**My TRY**
i gave a lot time to this problem.but i am very confused and couldnt find any proper approach. basically i dont have any clue about how to solve it. so i am giving my thoughts...

- it can be $1/2$
- or the probability will be same as of getting 50 heads. i.e. $100C50 *$ 1/2^50 $*$ 1/2^50

Comment: one possibility is that coins  have both side head

Comment: Are you supposed to assume it's a fair coin (equally likely to land heads or tails)?

Comment: yes fair coin ..

Comment: its a multiple choice question.. and there were no options like $1$ or $none$ $of$ $the$ $above$

Comment: The coins cannot be all fair.

Comment: @AndréNicolas then whats the answer according to you??

Comment: my answer is based  on fact that they have equal probabilities $1/2$,you can simple take  $p$ for general and if you get some nonsense equality it means that  they  are not equal probabilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coins are obviously not all fair. Assume that all our coins are biased in the same way, that is, each has probability $p$ of landing heads.

Then we get
$$\binom{100}{50}p^{50}(1-p)^{50}=\binom{100}{51}p^{51}(1-p)^{49}.$$
Simplification gives $50p=51(1-p)$. Solve for $p$.

Comment: there was written $52$ and i have changed  it :)

Comment: Thank you, I am typo-prone.

Comment: dont worry you are welcome  mister

Comment: You are welcome. Note that we assumed the coins all had the same degree of bias.  The analysis would be more sensible for a single coin being tossed $100$ times.

Answer (score 1):

so you have like this right

$((100!)*(1/2)^{50}*(1/2)^{50})/(50!*(50!))$

and second one

$((100!)*(1/2)^{51}*(1/2)^{49})/(51!*(49!))$

now you may try to set it equal to each other

just use some simple combination property like $50!=1*2*3.......*50$
and so on and also

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/408/408combinatorial.pdf

if we continue solution of @André Nicolas,we get that

$50*p=51-51p$

$101*p=51$

$p=51/101=0.504950495049505$

that is not exact $0.5$,that why it is not equal probabilities or fair

Comment: thanks for explaining @André Nicolas problem

Comment: you are welcome  good lucks

Comment: Erm 0 or 1? As you pointed out yourself. Where have they gone?